small signal overshoot reported in datasheet and stability
In datasheets of some op-amps namely ADA4522, NE5532, OP184 a small signal overshoot percentage has been reported mostly for an input pulse of 100mVp-p in a unity gain configuration. As far as I remember, small signal condition for a bipolar transistor so that  it still stays linear is that the input signal is well below the thermal voltage VT=26mV. (I don't remember the condition for a MOSFET).
Overshoot percentage on the other hand is related to phase margin and stability.
Now, can we relate this 100mVp-p overshoot percentage to phase margin as this screenshot from one of the TI precision lab videos?

The question is how small should the input pulse be to be able to use this overshoot vs. phase margin curve? 10mV as in the TI video or 100mV as the datasheets put it?

And what is the question?

Adding some "pF" (3 to 5 pF) on the feedback resistor will make disappear this overshoot ...

@Antonio51 it's a unity gain amplifier.

@Andy aka  Ok, I tried on an inverter ... 3 pF "could" not change "something" with this gain unity amplifier.

Note that it is OPx84 in place of OP824 ...

Note that something other appears on the output ...
Like this: we see that there is a spike and that Vo starts in the wrong direction ...

In the "inverting" circuit, it is quasi the same thing, except the "spike".
One capacitor is used.


Antonio, what do you mean with "wrong direction" (1st figure) ? Explanation for the "spike": Output response until the feedback brings the device back to linear operation (due to some delay in the fedback loop).

Just after the spike, voltage continue to be lower than the "steady" state, then it goes high. It is the input "capacitor" that makes that spike. Only in the "buffer" circuit, gain = 1. Does not occurs in the "inverter" circuit.

OK - I see what you mean. This effect is due to the transient which shows the approach to the steady-state condition (when feedback is effective).

The question is how small should the input pulse be to be able to use this overshoot vs. phase margin curve? 10mV as in the TI video or 100mV as the datasheets put it?
The input signal is a step - not a "pulse".
The step amplitude must be small enough to keep the amplifier within its linear amplifcation range.
More than that, the known relation between overshoot and phase margin applies for a 2nd order system only.
